# i get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the json script of this page but for some reason i get this error

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amongstfew.com/drops"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find("script", class_="draw_data_json").string.strip()

data = json.loads(script)

print(data['id']['title']['published_scope']['variants'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the code you have above the `json` object that comes back is a list.  So `data[id]` is trying to index into a list with a `str` which won't work

Here's my output for `data[0]`

```
In [9]: data[0]
Out[9]:
{'id': 1579513610342,
 'title': 'adidas - Yeezy BOOST 350 V2 (Sesame/Sesame/Sesame)',
 'published_scope': 'global',
 'variants': [{'id': 15564393054310,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 5 / UK 4.5 / EU 37 1/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 5 / UK 4.5 / EU 37 1/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393119846,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 5.5 / UK 5 / EU 38',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 5.5 / UK 5 / EU 38',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393152614,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 6 / UK 5.5 / EU 38 2/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710- US 6 / UK 5.5 / EU 38 2/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393185382,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 6.5 / UK 6 / EU 39 1/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 6.5 / UK 6 / EU 39 1/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393218150,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 7 / UK 6.5 / EU 40',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710- US 7 / UK 6.5 / EU 40',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393250918,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 7.5 / UK 7 / EU 40 2/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710- US 7.5 / UK 7 / EU 40 2/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393283686,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 8 / UK 7.5 / EU 41 1/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 8 / UK 7.5 / EU 41 1/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393316454,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 8.5 / UK 8 / EU 42',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710- US 8.5 / UK 8 / EU 42',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393349222,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 9 / UK 8.5 / EU 42 2/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710- US 9 / UK 8.5 / EU 42 2/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393381990,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 9.5 / UK 9 / EU 43 1/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 9.5 / UK 9 / EU 43 1/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564393414758,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 10 / UK 9.5 / EU 44',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 10 / UK 9.5 / EU 44',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564400001126,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 10.5 / UK 10 / EU 44 2/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 10.5 / UK 10 / EU 44 2/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564400033894,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 11 / UK 10.5 / EU 45 1/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710- US 11 / UK 10.5 / EU 45 1/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564400066662,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 11.5 / UK 11 / EU 46',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 11.5 / UK 11 / EU 46',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564400099430,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 12 / UK 11.5 / EU 46 2/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 12 / UK 11.5 / EU 46 2/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0},
  {'id': 15564400132198,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'title': 'US 12.5 / UK 12 / EU 47 1/3',
   'price': '999.00',
   'sku': 'F99710-US 12.5 / UK 12 / EU 47 1/3',
   'compare_at_price': '0.00',
   'inventory_quantity': 0}],
 'images': [{'id': 4849383309414,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'alt': None,
   'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1028/1839/products/yeezy-boost-350-v2---f99710---pair.jpg?v=1542971701'},
  {'id': 4849383571558,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'alt': None,
   'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1028/1839/products/yeezy-boost-350-v2---f99710---side.jpg?v=1542971701'},
  {'id': 4849382522982,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'alt': None,
   'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1028/1839/products/yeezy-boost-350-v2---f99710---front.jpg?v=1542971701'},
  {'id': 4849382424678,
   'product_id': 1579513610342,
   'alt': None,
   'src': 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1028/1839/products/yeezy-boost-350-v2---f99710---back.jpg?v=1542971701'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a list with keys.

Below is the line causing the trouble, and the code I think you want:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amongstfew.com/drops"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find("script", class_="draw_data_json").string.strip()

data = json.loads(script)

for item in data:
    print(data["id"] data["title"], data["published_scope"], data["variants"][0]])

# print(data['id']['title']['published_scope']['variants'][0]) # this line is causing trouble
```

Whenever you manipulate data, print it out and see how to get what you want.